# The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a similar issue like many others with error message "The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2."

My scenario is,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.[USP_PROCEDURE]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @LOADTIME DATETME2(7)
SET @LOADTIME = (SELECT LOADTIME FROM [LINKEDSERVERNAME].[DATABASENAME].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME] WHERE TABLENAME = 'XXXXXX')

INSERT INTO [CURRENTSERVER].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2,  
.... FROM TABLENAME JOIN TABLENAME1 ON ....
...
...

END
```

The table containing loadtime is present in Linked Server/Database and it is important value which is utilized further in where clause of my procedure via `@LOADTIME`. The query `SELECT LOADTIME ....` works fine when i try on present server individually.
But when i run it as part of procedure, my procedure fails with above mentioned error.
Linked server connection is set up and working fine. And my procedure needs to run on present server, which removes the scope of creating procedure on linked server. Hope my scenario is articulate.
All replies are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a general ANSI/ISO SQL problem. Please specify which DMBS you're using.

Comment: Are you sure that the row giving you the error are one of those rows? Also your insert into looks a bit suspicious. `[CURRENTSERVER].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]` should be `[DATABASENAME].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]` right?

Comment: Where's the database name?

Answer (score 1):

The line :

```
INSERT INTO [CURRENTSERVER].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]
```

Contains a server name but no database name. You should use

```
INSERT INTO [MYDATABASE].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]
```

or

```
INSERT INTO [CURRENTSERVER].[MYDATABASE].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]
```

or even

```
INSERT INTO [SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME]
```

if you are inserting in the same database as the stored procedure